# Reactive-native initial structure (Blank app)

Tags: react-native

I'm a web developer.

I'm starting today at react-native. I was able to install everything and configure **vscode** with the emulator.

When I run the command: (`react-native init myAPP`) is creating **app.js** already with a structure.

### My question:

As I come from the web, I know the basis for html development is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
.
.
.
</html>
```

### What is the basis of react-native development?

Comment: @JoshuaObritsch That was exactly what he needed. Enter your answer to mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that react native does not use html structure, the application is armed with native elements of react native. Use `<View> </View>` to generate a blank page and place your logic inside.

https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/